# FCEUX stops responding when i run this code made by me

Tags: lua

```
--llama a IUP

require("iuplua")

--Variables

on= 1

puntos1=memory.readbyte(0x0007DE) --Read the points value
puntos2=memory.readbyte(0x0007DF)
puntos3=memory.readbyte(0x0007E0)
puntos4=memory.readbyte(0x0007E1)
puntos5=memory.readbyte(0x0007E2)

p1=puntos1*100000 --Convert the raw values to it's game value
p2=puntos2*10000
p3=puntos3*1000
p4=puntos4*100
p5=puntos5*10

maxpuntaje=p1+p2+p3+p4+p5 --Calculate the final result

mundo=memory.readbyte(0x00075F) --Read the "world" value
nivel=memory.readbyte(0x000760) --Read the "level" value

estado=memory.readbyte(0x000770) --Read the mario "state" (00 not in game, 01 playing, 03 game over)

--Escribir las variables anteriores al morir


memory.writebyte(0x00075A,00) --Change the "lives" value to 1

while(on==1) do
estado=memory.readbyte(0x000770)
print(estado)
print(type(estado))
if(estado==03)then
    print("Puntuacion maxima (sesion actual) = ",maxpuntaje)
    print("Mundo y nivel Actual: ",mundo+1,"-",nivel+1)
end
```

end

(code edited)

[This is the state of 0x000770 when playing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsN5u.png)

[This is the state of 0x000770 when the Game Over scene jumps in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQuZn.png)

is there anything wrong? fceux just stop responding when i run this script, im new at stacks overflow and at programming so, every help will be welcome

Comment: Application stops responding because your code is a (possibly infinite) busy loop.  Can you use a timer for printing information?

Comment: I don't think so, the loop doesn't even start because it crashes before the conditions can match

Answer (score 0):

It's rather simple to debug this but more information is required

1. Make sure (estado==03) yields true and also print following variables and add into your question 
   `mundo=memory.readbyte(0x00075F)`
   `nivel=memory.readbyte(0x000760)`
   `estado=memory.readbyte(0x000770)`
   `print(mundo, nivel, estado)`
2. Check the types of these memory read vaiables i-g print(type(mundo))
3. Make Sure that the `if` condition checks against correct types
4. You realize that memonry is read once and while is always true

> Try this:

```
while(on==1) do
    estado=memory.readbyte(0x000770)
    print(estado)
    print(type(estado))
    if(estado==03)then
        print("Puntuacion maxima (sesion actual) = ",maxpuntaje)
        print("Mundo y nivel Actual: ",mundo+1,"-",nivel+1)
    end
end
```

Comment: I need this code to run when mario (Super Mario Bros. (NES)) dies, when it does it changes the memory value (0x000770) from 00 to 03. 1-Also all the others variables works fine, but the while loop doesn't (I tried without the loop while and it works fine), the others variables are integers, 2,3-I'm actually trying to convert them and test just in case. 4-And when the script starts running the value is 00, and it turn 03 when mario dies

Comment: estado=memory.readbyte(0x000770) will save one value. Check the edit

Comment: i tried, it constantly prints "1", that matchs the byte currrent value. but it stills crash. thanks for trying. If it helps, i can lend you my FCEUX version and my script so you can run it in yout pc and see the problem

Comment: I think you are comparing the wrong type, what error do you see? If read byte returns hex format you need to compare `estado==0x03` or `tonumber(estado)==3`

Comment: i tried what you suggested, now it constantly prints 1 number

Comment: what's the result of `print(type(estado))` ?

Comment: number apparently

Answer (score 0):

im so sorry for wasting your time, but i found the error, it was actually quite simple, there was a missing FCEU.frameadvance at the end of the cycle.
i dont know why it caused the emulator to crash but after putting it in place it stopped crashing. thanks to wsha for helping.

Comment: Good, that you found the solution, keep coming back